# Non breaking space after an href link is being included in the displayed hyperlink

Tags: email, hyperlink, href, non-breaking-characters

I am having an issue with emails being sent to users from a saved template. In this template there are non-breaking spaces to preserve formatting that is expected, and there is no issue forming the link or sending the email.

However it seems that after going through the mail server when the tags are displayed on their preferred mail service, some users are seeing the hypertext link malformed.

Example, 
This is how the raw link looks in the message we send,

```
Log in to <a href=\"https://website"\>https://website</a>&nbsp;to
```

And this is how users are reporting they are seeing the link in the message,

[https://website to](https://website)

Instead of,

https://website

I was able to pull the raw message from a test email after sending it to myself and didn't see that there was any issue with the encoding. Has anyone dealt with this before?

I am not sure if it may be better to try and strip out the character and replace it with a regular space? Or if there is another way to handle this?

Comment: @Hooman What I meant by the raw message, was that is how the sting is added to the email body so it displays as a link in the email browser.

Comment: Also the links are just in there to act as examples to show that the hard space and following text is being included in the URL. However I have found that it is due to a email security software that the user has installed. I'm in mobile and don't see anything to delete it, so I will when I can get in front of a computer.

Comment: thanks for clarification... I had misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping the link with a `<span>` and it might solve the problem... Note that I have replaced the escaped double quote `\"` with a single quote `'`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<label>Wrapped the link with a span</label>
<div>
    Log in to <span><a href='https://website'>https://website</a></span>&nbsp;to
</div>
</body>
</html>
```